# App download from site linked to Google play store

Tags: android, google-play

I know it might sound weird! Is it possible to link the number of downloads of your app from your site to reflect on Google play store?

Comment: I keep wondering what's wrong with my question as its being down voted?  Can someone please tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can access directly from the site, but you can use the [WhereDat app search API](http://wheredatapp.com/developers/)

Comment: If I understand,  I can only get the data from the Google play,  but I can not synchronize the data?

Comment: You can get the data from Goole Play to use on your own site, but you can not update the data at Google's. I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Good info!  If the download is made via website and an update is done via Google play ,  will it reflect as number of downloaded app?